# Do I need to use "have" or "has" for two inanimate actors?

Tags: grammar

Do I need to write "have" or "has" in the following sentence:

> Her genuine interest toward the subject and readiness to share her
> input in the lesson **have** served her really well over this year.

According to my knowledge of English grammar, it must be "have" because I have two actors: interest and readiness. However, the "Word" keeps changing it to "has". Why is it so? Is it because neither of the actors are living persons?

Comment: No. You are right: it needs "have", for the reasons you state. It does seem to need another *her* though: "...and *her* readiness..." I wonder if Word might then allow your **have**. The fact that the actors are inanimate is irrelevant, by the way.

Comment: I agree that 'have' is correct. While I think the tools like Word provides are probably a boon for people learning the language, I also think they're a bad tool. This kind of automated semantic correction is still in its infancy, and Word (and MS tools in general) tend to behave as though they know all the rules when they don't. Good for you for questioning what it suggested: next step, just turn it off, along with the spell check.